# Promises and async/await combination, ideal way to wait for asynchronous operations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Having async/await by itself in a function would return a "pending value" but if a promise used then the actual value will be returned in the end. Is this the ideal way to wait for the completion of asynchronous operations?

**This returns exactly what I want**

```
    var foundForm = await getDocument(query) //Returns the resulting document


 async function getDocument(query){
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
 MongoClient.connect  (url, async function(err, db) {
if (err) throw err;
 console.log(query)
db.collection("users").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(result);
  db.close();
  resolve(result) //   returns result;


       });
     });
  })
 }
```

**This doesnt return what I need:**

```
      var foundForm = await getDocument(query) //Returns 'pending'


    async function getDocument(query){

      MongoClient.connect  (url, async function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
    console.log(query)
        db.collection("users").find(query).toArray(function(err,                            result) {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(result);
    db.close();

   return result;
     });

     })
```

}

Comment: Can you use [edit] to clarify your code samples a bit. Also, your internal MongoClient.connect callback doesn't need `async` as far as I can see it, as you are not awaiting anything. I would venture that there is no ideal way of handling it, async/await is syntax sugar for promise implementation, and just handles some of the things away that people don't like about promise chains. The pending you get in the second piece of code, is simply because you are not resolving nor rejecting, so they are errors in how you code that piece

Comment: The first function immediately returns a Promise that resolves to the result of a callback, the second function returns nothing, the `return result;` is returning out of the callback not the `getDocument()` function

Comment: @WilliamLohan of course! That makes so much sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `getDocument` code needs to wait for an asynchronous operation that doesn't provide a Promise interface, `getDocument` shouldn't be an `async` function, because you need to create the promise manually. (And the callback you give to a non-promise-focussed function should almost never be an `async` function.)

```
function getDocument(query){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) {
                // Reject, don't throw
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(query);
            db.collection("users").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    // Reject, don't throw
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(result);
                db.close();
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Alternately, use promise-enabled versions of `MongoClient.connect` and `db.collection("users").find`. MongoDB has those available in its JavaScript API now (I'm afraid I don't have the details). Then you'd use an `async` function with `await`, **something** like this (according to [this blog post](https://medium.com/@tvalletta/promises-with-the-mongodb-node-client-d30c4549028d)):

```
// BE SURE TO DOUBLE-CHECK THE DETAILS
async function getDocument(query){
    const db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    const await result = db.collection("users").find(query).toArray();
    console.log(result);
    await db.close(); // No idea whether you need `await` here or not
    return result;
}
```

Comment: (And the callback you give to a non-promise-focussed function should almost never be an async function.) - Why is this considered bad? What would be the consequences to this?

Comment: Also the MongoDB javascript API snippet looks clean and fresh, awesome

Comment: @d12 - Because `async` functions always return a promise, but if the thing they're returning that promise to doesn't do anything with the promise, it sets you up for unhandled rejection errors. It also misleads you (and your potential readers), by giving the impression that the thing you're returning the promise to will do something useful with it. One classic example is people using `forEach` on an array and passing in an `async` callback, then wondering why it is that all of the array entries are passed through `forEach` before the first one is done with its work. :-)

Comment: Fabulous, this makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes. If you are targeting a platform that supports es6 async/await and want to utilize that, then if a library only exposes a callback api then "wrapping" the callback in a Promise (your first function) is how you'd accomplish that. Although you'd first want to make sure that the library doesn't offer Promise based api, then you could just return the Promise from the library and await that.